# Code completion in Netbeans for JSP EL

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, netbeans, netbeans-8

Say I have something like the following in a servlet:

```
POJO mo = new POJO();
mo.name = "Dude";
mo.age = 40;
request.setAttribute("mo", mo);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/test.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Now in the JSP file, I can use

```
...
<body>
Hello ${mo.name} you are ${mo.age}
</body>
```

Is there a way to get the editor to know that *mo* is of class POJO so I can get a list of properties?  Some way to declare that the JSP expects an instance of POJO named *mo* ?

Comment: i had the same problem and i already researched. But im afraid, this seems not to be work at the moment (NB 8). I read that this should work with Ecplise, but i did not check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No clear support for this in Netbeans, but at least JSF allows specifying an interface of sorts: [JSP EL parameter list / interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25625808/jsp-el-parameter-list-interface)