# JSP EL parameter list / interface

Tags: jsp, el

Is there at a mechanism (preferably compile-time) in JSP to specify required parameters for the JSP *accessible by EL*, or are the available objects always unknown?

There are cases where I want to specify that the JSP expects at least certain *named* parameters with certain *types*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look into [Tag Files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3257426/2782261), where the `attribute` page directive may suit your needs. This directive allows you to specify the name, type, whether the attribute is required, etc.